# How to gracefully stop job execution when one step fails in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

So I defined a Rundeck job which normally executes three steps:

1. run script to check remote directory for .csv files and rsync them
2. manipulate csv files
3. rsync the csvs back to remote dir

now I set up the script run on step 1 to finish with exit code 1 when there are no csv files in my remote directory, upon which it does not execute steps 2 and 3 - which is great! But the whole job is marked as having `failed` even though it just didn't need to execute the other steps.

Is it possible to conditionally execute steps 2 and 3 of my job such that if step 1 fails it is still marked as 'succeeded'?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with [Rundeck Error Handlers](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#error-handlers).

You will need to use the job context variable `${result.resultCode}` in your error handler code in order to get a return code.

As you don't want the job marked as failed after the Error Handler was successfully executed, you need to tick `Keep going on success` from WebUI or add `keepgoingOnSuccess="true"` to you job definition code.

But after the error handler was successfully executed, the job will continue step 2 and step 3, where you may need to inject your step 2 code for it.