# How to gracefully stop job execution when it’s killed on the Rundeck Web UI?

Tags: rundeck

This is the same question as [How to gracefully stop job execution when one step fails in Rundeck?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41729610/735926) except that I want to gracefully stop a job when it’s *killed* from the Web UI.

I’ve a similar job as the other question author: it dumps some SQL tables; manipulate a bit the dumps; upload them somewhere; and cleanup.

The issue comes when the job is terminated or killed before cleanup; it fills the disk with files that never get deleted. Rundeck supports [error handlers](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#error-handlers) for this but the docs say it’s for errors, not manual kills from the UI.

I’m able to cleanup on exit (success or error) by using the following in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
finish() {
  echo "remove dir $OUTPUT..."
  rm -Rf "$OUTPUT"
}
trap finish EXIT
# ... rest of the script ...
```

However this step doesn’t execute when the job is killed from the UI. I dug in Rundeck’s code source and it appears to simply use [`Thread#interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--), which I probably can’t catch.

Is there any solution to this issue? Right now I must `ssh` into the node and clean things up by myself when I kill the job.